# How can I turn on logging exceptions on startup of Websphere Application Server 16.0.0.4 (WLP)?

Tags: java, spring, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

On startup I get this one very non-descriptive log message telling me something went wrong on startup of my Spring-application:

```
W exception.occurred.while.running.ServletContainerInitializers.onStartup
             org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer@81337783
             web-app-name
```

And no trace of the exception anywhere. I've tried lots of tweaks in properties and server definition with no luck on getting Websphere to tell me what exception was thrown. That would a least give a hint of what is wrong with the app (possibly a bad or missing lib).

Is there a way of getting it to tell me more of what happened? And why is it so hard to get this piece of software to be a bit more informative?

I know of trace.log, but how do I tweak the settings so I get exactly the info I need and not tons of useless logs?

Comment: Consider moving to a newer version of Liberty like 17.0.0.4, it is possible the problem has been addressed.  Also, I don't think Liberty trace is at fault here, that exception is coming out of Spring, consider configuring it.

Comment: I have logging configured for Spring, but no logging is coming out since it's never getting configured before the exception is thrown.

It looks like the exception is caught by a Websphere-component/module, så there should be a way to log it. At least show me its name.

Comment: And BTW, it works with Spring 5.0.x, but not Spring 4.3.x, so there must be some lib missing or in conflict.

Comment: There is a bug in Liberty here. That is a message key for which there appears to be no associated message. Ultimately the SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup method has thrown an Exception. There should be an FFDC for the exception, but the message should also exist.

Comment: I found the culprit using trial and error. I was missing a commons-logging .jar-file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ServletContainerInitializer (SCI) processing in WebSphere Liberty should be covered by the trace:

```
<logging traceSpecification="*=info=enabled:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer*=all:com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer*=all" maxFileSize="40" maxFiles="20" traceFormat="BASIC"/>
```

See these for more information about enabling trace in Liberty:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/as_ditamaps/was900_welcome_liberty.html

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_trouble.html

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_logging.html

Also, the exception information *might* appear in a different log than where that warning occurs.  Make sure to check all of the generated log files, including those in the FFDC folder.

Comment: I have the trace specifiation in a bootstrap.properties file. Is that different than setting the logging-element attribute traceSpecification in server.xml?

Comment: Trace specifications in bootstrap.properties take effect sooner than those in server.xml, but are otherwise the same.